# For loop through list of strings

Tags: python

I am trying to save certain information out of xarray in a loop. I keep getting an error msg.
Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

samples = {}

samples['first'] = [1,2]
samples['second'] = [3,4]

samples

categories = list(samples.keys())

categories

dta = []

for i in range(len(categories)):
    dta[categories[i]] = samples[categories[i]]

dta
```

I get an error saying "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: Did you try to print `categories[i]` to see what it is? That said, code like `for i in range(len(categories))` is anti-pattern in python

Comment: Also, do you really want `dta` to be a list?

Comment: What is the actual output you're expecting? How do you expect anyone to help when you didn't even mention what you need?!

Comment: Can you remove imports for `numpy`, `pandas` and `xarray` to show a [example]. Also: Do we really need `categories` as intermediary variable if you want to transform keys of dict `samples` to list `dta` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this to add data:

```
for i in range(len(categories)):
    dta.append(samples[categories[i]])
```

Instead of:

```
for i in range(len(categories)):
    dta[categories[i]] = samples[categories[i]]
```

`dta` is a `list`

You can also do a list comprehension if you want:

```
dta = [samples[categories[i]] for i in range(len(categories))]
#[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

**Edit:**

```
dta = {}

for i in range(len(categories)):
    dta[categories[i]] = samples[categories[i]]

print(dta)

{'first': [1, 2], 'second': [3, 4]}
```

Comment: Thanks @God is One. Using this method, dta list doesn't keep the keys right? it becomes a list of dataframes without the 'key' identifier. I was hoping for something where the key identifier could be kept.

Comment: Do you want a dictionary?

Comment: Oh I get it now. I just change dta to a dictionary?

Comment: yes. you are right

Comment: @Stata_user So `dta` is just ..... `samples`?! What's the point?

Answer (score 0):

#### Variable `samples` is of type `dict`

```
samples = {}

samples['first'] = [1,2]
samples['second'] = [3,4]
```

It has textual keys `first`, `second` of type `str`.

#### To add those values to variable `dta` of type `list`

Your code has issues:

```
dta = []

for i in range(len(categories)):
    dta[categories[i]] = samples[categories[i]]
```

Will fail because `categories[i]` references the list-element correctly by integer index `i` but, the value of element is a string which can't be used to index the list `dta`.

Correct indexing would be `dta[i]` if the list has an element at position `i`. But your list is initially empty, see `dta = []`. So you have to use `append()`.

#### Fix

Instead of a for-i loop using `range(len(categories))` you can also use a for-each loop:

```
dta = []
for value in samples.values():
    dta.append( value )
```

Another simpler approach would be direct conversion during definition:
`dta = list(samples.values())`

Compare both data-structures afterwards in the Python shell:

```
>>> samples
{'first': [1, 2], 'second': [3, 4]}
>>> dta
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simplify the code to this:

```
samples = {
    "first": [1, 2],
    "second": [3, 4],
}

dta = list(samples.values())
print(dta)  # Output: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

It basically takes `list` of all the `values` in the dictionary `samples`.